# vue component(static) not working. I want to solution

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

After configuring the project with vue-cli 3.x,
I defined this component in main.js.

By the way,
**Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.**

I have not been able to proceed with the above error.
How do I use global components?

code..
main.js

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('staticComponent', {
    template: '<div>{{ msg }}</div>',
    data() {
        return {
            msg: 'Hello Static Component'
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: (h) => {
        return h(App)
    },
})
```

App.vue

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <StaticComponent/>
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either only use `PascalCase` or only use `kebab-case` but *never* use `lowerCamelCase` when naming components. This is because `vue` has standards when referencing JSX in templates.

[codepen illustrating this works fine](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOwQwz)

Comment: Hi?
It still does not work in my code.

I do not know if I will attach some of the contents of my package.json file.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }